# Is there any way to set a global variable in DQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, dql

Is there any way to set a global variable into DQL?

I've this code in SQL (working like charm) that I've to translate to DQL. It isn't returning any result, just perform action and finish.

```
//COPIAR A RANKANTERIOR
    UPDATE SistemaPuntuacions SET rankingAnterior = rankingActual
//ACTUALITZAR SEGONS ELS PUNTS DEL USUARI
    set @rank=0;
    UPDATE SistemaPuntuacions SET rankingActual= @rank := @rank +1
    ORDER BY punts DESC;
```

I can't find any documentation related to that...

```
//Copy to oldRank
   UPDATE RankSystem SET oldRank = RankNow
//Update RankNow by points
   set @rank=0;
   UPDATE RankSystem SET RankNow= @rank := @rank +1
   ORDER BY points DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DQL is **Doctrine Query Language**  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

So DQL is actually a query language and not suited for handling global variables. You can query databases and manipulate them, that's it.

In DQL you  can define parameters to be passed to your query , [Doctrine2 using setParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988866/doctrine2-using-setparameters)

However where is your actual DQL code?

---

Besides try to have your code comments and keywords to be in english to make it understandable for us.

---

You don't need to translate it in dql, you can use native query, too. Have a look here

[I need to put SQL native in query Builder Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436312/i-need-to-put-sql-native-in-query-builder-doctrine2)

[Using native SQL query without entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860838/using-native-sql-query-without-entity-class?rq=1)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, @artworkad it's translated now. I don't have any DQL code. It's just this coded in sql language, and I've to translate it to DQL somehow to implement it into a Symfony2 script.